# Trying to find an exhaustive list of events (like 'click')

Tags: javascript, html

Learning about events like `'click'`, I thought it'd be useful to seek out MDN to have a handy reference of all possible events that I could read up on (and reference when I discover them in other people's code).

Basically, a reference of all that you could replace `'click'` with here:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', handler)
```

What I found:

[List of common ones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#Standard_events) (search ‘Standard Events’).

[Looks okay but doesn't include 'DOMContentLoaded' etc.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize)

An exhaustive list would be nice - is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked this, this is all the listing of events that can be captured in JS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: This list does not contain *all* the events that can be captured in JS, For instance, MeidaRecorder.onstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/onstart)  is not listed there. But anyway, having a list of *all* the events that can be captured in JS is not possible since one can create their own custom events.